# Like plugin for fb application url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta

I have a iframe application, in that app i put a fb like plugin.

the plugin has field of 'which url to like', i filled with my app url 
(i.e. "http://apps.facebook.com/demoapp")

When any one click like, it posting on their wall like below image,

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51378137/Screen%20Shots/fb_like.png

it not showing proper image as well as decription.

Is this correct way we giving apps.facebook.com/demoapp url for like plugin,

if its correct means how display valid description..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put right "og" meta tags

More info 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/news/
http://ogp.me/
or
http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags